# What is the default list of installed packages in kubuntu (14.04)?

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu

I'm converting another person's notebook from lubuntu to kubuntu, and wanted to check what packages are installed / are not installed relative to a clean kubuntu setup.

Thus, what is the output of `dpkg --get-selections` in a clean kubuntu 14.04 install?

(I know I can probably grab an image and find out, but in case this is easier)

Comment: You can check the [manifest](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04/release/kubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.manifest). The manifest lists packages on a live image, and the installed version is that minus a few things like the installer, Gparted, some language packs, etc.

Comment: Another way to check is through [distrowatch.com](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=kubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below a link providing the output of `dpkg --get-selections` in a clean kubuntu 14.04 install.

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/10147788/

I did the installation without a network adapter so that nothing altered the final system setup.